# What is a multiple compilation, how is working and why i should use it?

Tags: c, compilation

I am learning C and I just read the term multiple compilation.
Till now I had a single file.c and I used the command `gcc file.c` to compile it and then `./a.out` to execute it. But I got confused a little bit. When should I use the multiple compilation instead of the single and which would be the possible reasons that they will lead me to prefer a multiple compilation instead of the single?
 I searched it and I found some articles but they didn't cover fully my questions. [1 (this is for c++)](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jestes/cop3330/notes/compilation.html) , [2](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_11.html)
If i undestood well if I have some files.c in my project eg file1.c, file2.c and then i want to link them, i execute

```
gcc file1.c
gcc file.c
gcc file1.o file2.o //somehow i have to create the .o files..
```

Thank you..

Comment: `.o` files are objects. they're already compiled code. you need to link them into an executable

Comment: `gcc -c` will create `.o` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many steps to compiling.

When you invoke `gcc` it will create by default an executable file i.e. all steps in one go:

- `.c` -> `.i` preprocessor
- `.i` -> `.s` compiler
- `.s` -> `.o` assembler
- `*.o` -> `a.out` linker

Generally the first two take up the most time. If you have a large project then recompiling the entire project may take a lot of time when you are developing. So the compiler allows you to stop at a certain point and reuse previous results of files that have not changed:

- `gcc -E` for preprocess only (rarely used)
- `gcc -S` compile, but don't assemble. Useful for debugging or optimising assembly
- `gcc -c` compile, assemble, but don't link. This is the most commonly used one and produces object files. Those contain your assembled functions (object code), but it's not capable of running because not all functions may be present yet, library functions are missing and the executable header has not been linked in.

The final step `gcc -o executable *.o` will then take all those and link them together to create an executable. Optionally linking libraries into it.

Generally having all functions in one source file will allow the compiler to do the more optimisations (i.e. inlining), but at the cost of compile time.

Have a look at https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~btp200/pages/images/compile_link.png

Comment: Sth more, `makefile` command is sth similar to my question? @SergeyL.

Comment: @Nat95 I don't get the question. If you are referring to GNU `make` then that is a completely different topic. It is a program that can automate some compilation steps for you. I suggest you search for GNU make and read the documentation if you are interested in that.

Answer (score 3):

Compilation takes time. There's no point in re-compiling C code that hasn't changed. So, for large projects, it makes sense to split the code into multiple files (typically not randomly of course, but into modules of different functionality) and compile them only when needed.

Linking is the process of taking a bunch of object code (what the `.o` files are called) and turning them into a single program.

Comment: Sth more, `makefile` command is sth similar to my question? @unwind